# Call a script in parallel in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to run a script in parallel to my Qt program and am having trouble starting it as a separate process. Check out my attempts below and let me know what you see wrong.

The first attempt was just a system call:

```
system("python3 startprocess.py");
```

This works but it also stops the program while running it.

I then followed this guy https://forum.qt.io/topic/92205/writing-commands-to-linux-bash with no success. No errors, just no start of my script.

I am trying this after I saw the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProgram) and have the below code.

```
QProcess process;
process.start("python3 startprocess.py");
process.waitForStarted();
```

I am just wanting to start this script and have it run at the same time as my C++ code. Perhaps I am using the QProcess wrong?

**UPDATE:**
It was a lot easier to use [QThreading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaGqGhRW5Ks) and the original system call.

Comment: Using QThread might be easier, but could lead to bugs. I suggest trying again with the QProcess!

Comment: As my rules of thumb on how to use `QProcess` without trouble: 1. Avoid all the waitForXxx methods (they cause event loop to be re-entered, which can lead to issues in complex applications, which means all GUI applications). 2. Connect *all* the signals of `QProcess`, at least to a lambda with `qDebug` print, so you will notice when things don't work the way you expect. 3. Pass the parameters as `QStringList` to avoid surprises with splitting at spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `QProcess` doesn't have the file path and fails to find and start it! I suggest first to use the full file path! Also check the [QProcess::setWorkingDirectory](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory) and [QProcess::setProcessEnvironment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProcessEnvironment) that are useful to handle this case!

---

### Update

In order to prevent the `QProcess` to be killed while running and without freezing the GUI, you need to define it as a pointer, then connect the `QProcess::finished` event; in the slot, you can check the exit code and delete the sender using `QObject::deleteLater` method. Check both the [Qt example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details) and the [QProcess::finished](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished).

---

### Update 2

Try this code:

```
auto process = new QProcess(this);
connect(process, QOverload<int,QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), 
[this](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus) 
{
    if (exitStatus == QProcess::ExitStatus::CrashExit 
        || exitCode != 0) {
        // Process error!
    } else {
        // Process OK!
    }
});
process->setWorkingDirectory("startprocess.py folder location");
process->start("python3 startprocess.py");
if (!process->waitForStarted(-1)) {
    // Failed to start process
    delete process;
}
```

Comment: Ok tried setworkingdirectory right above the process.start and QProcess "destroyed it while python was still running" which is odd with the waitforstarted in there. I'm trying but don't understand the setProcessEnviroment but I'll give it a shot. Thank you.